# Render a document in printing order, two pages per "page"

Tags: pdftex, rendering

I have an existing memoir document that I would like to physically print and bind in a book. It is 72 pages, made up of 6 signatures of 3 folios each. I would like to make the document render two pages of content on each "page" of the pdf, and to display them in proper order for ease of printing. For example, pretending we only need to print the first 12 content pages:

```
outside
 front    |  back
[ 2  11 ] | [ 1  12 ] %page number
[ 4  9  ] | [ 3  10 ]
[ 6  7  ] | [ 5  8  ]
inside
```

I would want the rendered output to have the pages in the order:

2&11, 4&9, 6&7, (pages are flipped and put back in the printer) 1&12, 3&10, 5&8

If it is better to do this in an external program that is fine. I have not been able to find anything!

Comment: Did you look at `pdfpages` package?  or the `psnup` tool?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! TeX Live has the `pdfnup` utility that could be what you're looking for.

Comment: You should try the booklet package. Really easy to use. And no need for any external utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give as an example the code for a booklet job (a 10 pages short story, including the titlepage) I did a few years ago, with the `pdfpages` package:

I had a pdf document compiled in A5 format, with one title page, and and no blank page after the title page, so that page 1 was on the second physical page.

My aim was to print it on sheets of A4 paper, with a blank page after the title page. Here is the very short code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, twoside]{book}%

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages = {1,{},2-10},signature=12,landscape]{LeDiamant_de_l_HerbeA5.pdf}

\end{document}
```

In the pages specification, `{}` is for the blank page that has to be introduced between the first and the second physical pages. Note that in case of 2×1 or 1×2 printing, for the `pdfpages` package, the `signature` is the smallest multiple of 4 that is greater than or equal to the number of pages (including the blank ones).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a texlive installation, you can type "texdoc pdfbook" on the commandline and get the manpage of pdfbook. In short: `pdfbook --suffix ’sig4’ --batch myfile1.pdf myfile2.pdf` 
will result in files named ’myfile1-sig4.pdf’ and ’myfile2-sig4.pdf’. (I have copied this sentence from the manpage).